# Cambiar color de fondo de los elementos del drawer al ser pulsados

Tags: android, android-drawerlayout

En el dichero `activity_main_drawer.xml`defino los elementos del `Navigation Drawer` y los separado en 3 bloques tal y como se aprecia
en la imagen mostrada al final del post.

A la hora de seleccionar un `elemento` del primer bloque (Inicio, Avisos, Instalaciones, favoritos), el fondo de color de este se vuelve gris (Correcto), pero
si se selecciona algún `elemento` del segundo (Localización, Actividades, Horario) o del tercer bloque (Idioma) no cambia el color de fondo del elemento.

`activity_main_drawer.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_hasiera"
            android:title="@string/nav_hasiera" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oharrak"
            android:title="@string/nav_oharrak" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instalazioak"
            android:title="@string/nav_instalazioak" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gustokoak"
            android:title="@string/nav_gustokoak" />
    </group>
    <item android:title="@string/filtrar_por">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_lokalizazioa"
                android:title="@string/nav_lokalizazio" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ekintzak"
                android:title="@string/nav_ekintzak" />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ordutegia"
                android:title="@string/nav_ordutegia" />
        </menu>
    </item>
    <item android:title="@string/opciones">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hizkuntza"
                android:title="@string/nav_hizkuntza" />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

Captura después de pulsar en el `item` `Instalaciones`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Y lo que quieres es que también cambie igual que el primer grupo?

Comment: Sí. Pero ya lo he conseguido añadiendo `android:checkable="true"` a los items del grupo dos y tres.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La solución es añadir `android:checkable="true"`a los items del segundo y tercer grupo.

Así queda el código completo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_hasiera"
            android:title="@string/nav_hasiera" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_oharrak"
            android:title="@string/nav_oharrak" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_instalazioak"

            android:title="@string/nav_instalazioak" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/nav_gustokoak"
            android:title="@string/nav_gustokoak" />

    </group>

    <item android:title="@string/filtrar_por">
        <menu>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_lokalizazioa"
                android:title="@string/nav_lokalizazio"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ekintzak"
                android:title="@string/nav_ekintzak"
                android:checkable="true"/>
            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_ordutegia"
                android:title="@string/nav_ordutegia"
                android:checkable="true"/>
        </menu>
    </item>

    <item android:title="@string/opciones">
        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/nav_hizkuntza"
                android:title="@string/nav_hizkuntza"
                android:checkable="true"/>
        </menu>
    </item>


</menu>
```

Comment: Perfecto que lo solucionaste, recuerda en marcar la respuesta como correcta

Answer (score 0):

Es correcto, con el `android:checkable="true"` puedes resolver este problema, dejo algunas referencias para este tipo de características dentro del tag.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html